# App Engine - Query for logs in a different project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using:

```
LogService ls = LogServiceFactory.getLogService();
LogQuery lq = new LogQuery();
```

and it's working fine and pulling logs down from the project the code is running in.

However what I want to do it query the logs from a different App Engine project. I don't see any way to pass OAuth credentials into the LogService or the LogQuery to get logs from somewhere else.

Is possible?

Comment: Did you try doing this as a urlfetch from one app to the other?

Comment: That's a possibility but the LogService is still querying the running project and not a different one. There are lots of ways to get the logs across from one project to the other but what I really want is to just read directly from the second project if I can.